# HTML CSS - Make icon change color when clicked (like a link)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, visited

When you click a link, typically it changes to purple, so you know that you've clicked that link. Usually resetting once you refresh or leave the page. Is there a way to make an icon (SVG or ) act like a link when clicked? And not just the last one clicked. It would be every single icon that gets clicked. I was trying to use the :visited pseudo, but it wasn't working.

```css
.visit {
  fill: lightblue;
}

.visit:visited {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a>
```

jQuery and JavaScript answers are fine, but if there's a way to do this with just HTML and CSS, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:visited` is a link-related pseudo-class. It must be applied to the `<a>` tag.

```css
.visit {
  fill: lightblue;
}

a:visited .visit { /* Fix here */
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a>
```

Comment: Ah that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this and use a different number after # for every element you want to use this on.

```css
.visit {
  fill: lightblue;
}

a:visited .visit {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use the `active` pseudo for this. This will make it so that when the link is active (i.e. clicked) turn green in this case.

For more information on the `active` pseudo, please see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) site

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
}
  
.visit {
  fill: lightblue;
}

.visit:active {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a><a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a><a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a><a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a><a href="#"><svg>
   <rect width='300' height='100' class='visit'></rect>
</svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample!

```css
.box {
  width:  300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .visit {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.box:link .visit {
  fill: #999;
}

.box:hover .visit {
  fill: #3f9;
}

.box:active .visit {
  fill: #f93;
}

.box:visited .visit {
  background: #39f;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class='box'>
  <svg>
    <rect class='visit'>
    </rect>
  </svg>
</a>
```